# How to Remove Default Message From Liferay Portlet

Tags: java, liferay, liferay-6

I am adding following lines in portlet.xml

```xml
<init-param>
  <name>add-process-action-success-action</name>
  <value>false</value>
</init-param>
```

but it is not working...please help me out..

Comment: http://proliferay.com/how-to-hide-default-error-message-in-liferay/

Comment: The above reference describes about hiding default success and error messages from liferay portlet.

Comment: @ParkashKumar....I have tried from this link....it is also giving the same code i have added in my code snippet..but it is not working..

Comment: Which message(s) are you trying to hide? Error or success?

Comment: @ParkashKumar....Error and success both....

Comment: Can you also share the other relevant code? Like `processAction`.

Comment: Have you find the solution? @ParkashKumar

Answer (score 2):

Try this in your Controller Action

```
// Hiding the default Error Message
    PortletConfig portletConfig = (PortletConfig) request.getAttribute(JavaConstants.JAVAX_PORTLET_CONFIG);
    LiferayPortletConfig liferayPortletConfig = (LiferayPortletConfig) portletConfig;
    SessionMessages.add(request, liferayPortletConfig.getPortletId()
                    + SessionMessages.KEY_SUFFIX_HIDE_DEFAULT_ERROR_MESSAGE);
```